# How can I remove the space between listing and text in scrartlc?

Tags: listings

I am trying to write one line of code in a listing in scrartlc. The problem is that the space between the listing and the text below is too big.

How it looks when using scrartlc:

[image]

This is how it looks like when changing `\documentclass[parskip=full]{scrartlc}` to `\documentclass{article}`:

[image]

I want to get the same result as I got with `article` but with `scrartlc`. How do I get it like this?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[parskip=full]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\lstdefinestyle{customjava}{
language=Java,
keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{green!40!black},
\lstset{escapechar=@, style=customjava}
}

\begin{document}
test
\begin{lstlisting}
public int a;
\end{lstlisting}
test
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want to remove this space for all `lstlistig`s or just for a single one? If it's just for a single one maybe `\end{lstlisting}
\vskip-\belowdisplayskip
test` could help.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works. What could I do for removing the space for all listings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The additional vertical space comes from the `parskip` option. You will get a similar issue if you use the standard class `article` with package `\parskip`.

If you do not want to remove option `parskip=full`, then you could use

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newlength\savedparskip
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{lstlisting}{\setlength\savedparskip{\parskip}}
\lstset{belowskip=\dimexpr-\savedparskip+\medskipamount\relax}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[
  parskip=full
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\lstdefinestyle{customjava}{
language=Java,
keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{green!40!black}
}
\lstset{escapechar=@, style=customjava}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newlength\savedparskip
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{lstlisting}{\setlength\savedparskip{\parskip}}
\lstset{belowskip=\dimexpr-\savedparskip+\medskipamount\relax}

\begin{document}
test
\begin{lstlisting}
public int a;
\end{lstlisting}
test
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could define one or more lstenvironments with custom settings.

```
\documentclass[parskip=full]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}



\makeatletter
\lstnewenvironment{rmlisting}
    {\lstset{escapechar=@, language=Java,
  showspaces=false,
  showtabs=false,
  breaklines=true,
  showstringspaces=false,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  commentstyle=\color{DarkBlue},
  keywordstyle=\color{Green},
  stringstyle=\color{Purpple}}
    }
    {
    \vspace*{-12pt}   
    }
\makeatother    

\begin{document}

test
\begin{lstlisting}
 public int a;
\end{lstlisting}
test


test
\begin{rmlisting}
 public int a; @%and here your comment etc@
\end{rmlisting}
test

\end{document}
```

See here how it works

[image]